# Create yum repository with keys

Tags: ftp, centos, yum, gnupg

I want to setup a repository on yum server with keys so that only the client having the key can connect to the yum server and can use the yum repository. Other clients not having key shouldn't be able to use the repository or better should not be able to connect to the yum server.
I have tried doing this using the gpgcheck and gpgkey but when I tested from client without keys it is still able to access and install packages.
I have hosted the repository for anonymous ftp access so that the client can access the server using ftp protocol, is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the connection mechanism is the issue.

`gpgcheck` in the yum repository config controls whether yum checks the packages it retrieves from the repository against the installed gpg keys (keys listed by `gpgkey` are automatically retrieved by yum if they are listed the first time it needs to install a package from the repository).

To do the sort of thing you want you are going to want to give the clients an SSL certificate and key (the `sslclientcert` and `sslclientkey` settings in yum.conf) and configure the server to check for this before allowing access (which means `ftps` or `https`).

Comment: how to generate SSLClientcert and sslclientkey ?